# Angular app container changes application size

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I read that one of the best practices in angular is to keep the application in a column container.
when I did that pages have large padding on right and left sides.
I tried many ways with no results.

app.component.html

``

```
<header fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center"> 
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</header>
<main fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center"> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
</main>
<footer fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</footer>
```

```

home.component.html

```
 <div fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" style="height:100vh">

    <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" class="parent">
        <div fxFlex="50" class="hero" >
            <img src=".\assets\home\hero1.png" alt="" style="height:100vh">
        </div>

        <div fxFlex="50" class="hero">
            <h5>We are doing</h5>
            <h1>Ideas to come true</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quidem, consequuntur!</p>

        </div>
      </div>  
      
</div>
```

[That was the result I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnyOo.png)

My question is how to keep elements fill page width without that margin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to set `margin: 0 ` in `hero` in your css

Comment: it worked for hero only, but the navbar and footer still the same entered with margins

Comment: Then try to set `margin: 0` in your navbar css class too